# Remove creator owner permissions on a registry key using a security template

Tags: security, permissions, windows-registry

Is there any way to remove the permissions of the "creator owner" object on a registry key using security templates? It seems like you can either allow or deny objects permission using the template, but not clear a permission... so I'm not sure how to get rid of the object here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using workaround #2 listed here fixes this issue for me: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321470